# I have a very simple question about TRIGGERS in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, triggers, relational-database

I really did not understand the issue of **Trigger**, and I would be *very happy* if you help me. It is really important to me. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q3uwD.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Briefly

A TRIGGER in MySQL is a stored program. We say that a trigger is "fired" when a DML statement (INSERT,UPDATE or DELETE) is executed.

Best way to get a handle on them is to write one, and test it.

"when updating a ship name in the ships table"

< rant >why do academics insist on using *plural* for table names... grrr... the table name should be the name of the tuple, what *one* row represents < /rant >

we want our trigger to fire on an UPDATE statement, that attempts to modify a row (or rows) in table ship, so it's going to need to have this"

```
BEFORE UPDATE ON ship
```

we also want to detect a change being made to the value of the ship_name column, so we are going to want to compare the current value to the new value being assigned, to see if they are the same or not

We could write a test to see if they are equal

```
    IF ( NEW.ship_name = OLD.ship_name ) THEN
```

But this test is incomplete, doesn't detect NULL value matches NULL, so we are going to be a little more precise, and find *any* change, including NULL to non-NULL,

```
   IF NOT ( NEW.ship_name <=> OLD.ship_name ) THEN
```

---

Let's say we define a trigger

```
 DELIMITER $$

 DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS ship_bu $$

 CREATE TRIGGER ship_bu
 BEFORE UPDATE ON ship
 FOR EACH ROW
 BEGIN
    -- if the value of ship_name on this row is being changed
    IF NOT ( NEW.ship_name <=> OLD.ship_name ) THEN

        -- we can do something useful here, for example
        UPDATE some_other_table t
           SET t.ship_name = NEW.ship_name
         WHERE t.ship_name = OLD.ship_name
        ;
        -- note that we won't match a NULL value of ship_name 

    END IF;
 END$$
```

Now when we execute a statement like this:

```
 UPDATE ship s SET s.ship_name = 'NCC-1701' WHERE s.ship_name = 'Enterprise';
```

If that matches a row in the ship table, the trigger will be fired, for that row.
In the trigger, the value of `OLD.ship_name` will be the value of the ship_name column from the row in the table.

For any rows that match the condition in the WHERE clause, we know that will be 'Enterprise'. (If the column is defined with _ci (case insensitive) collation, we could also get a value of 'eNTeRPRiSe' which would also match.)

Also inside the trigger, the value of `NEW.ship_name` will be the value that is being assigned to the column by the statement, in this case `'NCC-1701`.

In a BEFORE INSERT and BEFORE UPDATE trigger, we can also assign values to NEW.colum_name.  We could do `SET NEW.ship_name = 'Lollipop';` once the BEFORE UPDATE trigger finishes, MySQL goes back to the UPDATE statement to finish processing.

Note that an INSERT trigger has access to NEW.col but not OLD.col (there is no "old" row.  Similarly, the DELETE trigger can access OLD.col, not not NEW.col.

Reference:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/triggers.html

Comment: Thank you very much for these **nice comments and quick feedback**. If you only answer the 3rd and 4th questions, I would be very pleased. Because I don't have the luxury of making mistakes, I have to pass the course.

Comment: a brief note on naming conventions for triggers, in our shop, triggers are named starting with the table that they are on, and then underscore, and then either b (before) or a (after) and then either i (insert) or u (update) or d (delete)... so looking for triggers on the table ship,  they are going to start with "ship" and we know e.g that _bu is a BEFORE UPDATE trigger, and _bi  is an BEFORE INSERT trigger.

Comment: Making mistakes is part of the learning process, not a luxury. Fortunately, we can make mistakes in a development environment, and learn from them, without having aircraft falling from the sky, driverless cars careening across lanes, and nuclear reactors going critical. Luxury is being able to make time to learn, and to make mistakes that don't cause any harm. Now is the time to do that.

Answer (score 2):

The MySQL trigger is a database object that is associated with a table. It will be activated when a defined action is executed for the table. The trigger can be executed when you run one of the following MySQL statements on the table: INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE and it can be invoked before or after the event.